# Does Spark SQL supports collation as it does in sql Server

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

In Sql server through this query **select SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION')** we get to know collation property to be used.
Does the same supports in Spark SQl in databricks platform.
If it doesn't then what types can used to **behave similar property**

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is any thing like that in Spark SQL . In TSQL once you have set the collation the queries will behave as case-insenstive/ case-senstive, depending on what you have set . But in the world of SPARK you will have to write code and implement the same .

In short we do not have any property like that in Spark-SQL.